# Problema con php y batch

Tags: php, mysql, batch

Ya configure `apache` para que PHP pueda ejecutar archivos `.bat`, tengo que mover archivos de otro servidor a mi equipo para después hacer operaciones con el, al ejecutar el `batch` manualmente si me hace la función, pero al ejecutarlo desde `php` ya no, cabe decir que tengo otro `batch` que mueve un archivo local a otra ruta local y al ejecutarlo desde el `php` si me realiza la acción.

`Batch` que se conecta a un servidor:

```
Copy "\\180.176.114.15\respaldos\proyecto_bboo\error.txt" 
"C:\xampp\htdocs\caet\error.txt"
```

`php` que lo ejecuta:

```
<?php
exec("C:/xampp/htdocs/caet/copi2.bat");
?>
```

Al imprimir el error dice `Acceso denegado`. debo poner el archivo `batch` en una ruta especial o que mas tengo que configurar en mi `php.ini`.

Ya probe la solucion que me dieron abajo y aun asi no funciona dejo captura del batch y al ejecutar el batch desde el php[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Le puedes pasar un paràmetro `$output` e imprimirlo: por ejemplo: `exec("C:/xampp/htdocs/caet/copi2.bat",$output); print_r($output);`. También puedes usar `var_dump`... ten en cuenta que `$output` siempre devolverá un array. [Ver el Manual de PHP al respecto](http://www.php.net/function.exec)

Comment: Gracias hice esto $err=exec("C:/xampp/htdocs/caet/copi2.bat");
 print_r($err);

Comment: me dice Acceso denegado. donde puedo checar eso con detalle, no debo poner el batch en una ruta especial?

Comment: ¿Tú usuario tiene privilegios de acceso para esta ruta: `C:/xampp/htdocs/caet/`?  Eso sí, ten mucho cuidado al dar privilegios...

Comment: si tengo privilegios  para la ruta de xamp y la externa,me imagino que php no los tiene por eso no me da acceso

Comment: Parece que tienes que darle permiso sobre esa ruta al usuario `www-data` que es el que ejecuta los comandos de consola.

Comment: nota: para saber con que user se identifica php `$err=exec("whoami"); print_r($err);` en unix te dira el username en win te dira maquina\username

Answer (score 1):

En php para ejecutar un archivo bat se debe de escribir el exec con el ejecutable del comando cmd y los parámetros correspondientes, por ejemplo:

```
exec('C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c "C:/xampp/htdocs/caet/copi2.bat"');
```

Por la parte del copy remoto, el comando copy lo estas usando sobre el protocolo SMB, tu Explorer probablemente esta ya loggeado con usuario y contraseña para la conexión con la computadora destino, pero tu apache y ambiente de PHP muy probablemente no lo están. Probablemente podría funcionar loggearte al SMB desde el archivo bat de la siguiente forma:

```
net use "\\180.176.114.15\respaldos" /user:"usuario" "contrasena" /persistent:no
copy "\\180.176.114.15\respaldos\proyecto_bboo\error.txt" "C:\xampp\htdocs\caet\error.txt"
net use "\\180.176.114.15\respaldos" /delete /yes
```

En la primer linea se está loggenado al smb de la computadora remota ahí hay que poner el usuario y la contraseña que usas para loggearte, si no hay quita la parte de la  contraseña y usuario, la segunda linea es tu copy original, y la última es para desloggearte.

Este es un bash ejecutado en mi computadora correctamente con la contraseña y la ruta de red y permisos en las carpetas necesarios:

[image: Ejecucion de bash con samba y usuario y password]

Comment: muchas gracias mañana voy a probar ya que estoy en casa,mañana te cuento como me fue

Comment: no me funciono :(

Comment: ¿Que error te mando?, ¿si ejecutas el bash hay error?

Comment: si ejecuto el bash todo funciona correctamente,ya subi la imagen en el post sobre lo que me muestra en cmd y en php gracias

Comment: Es que la ruta que debes poner en la primer línea al loggearte al samba remoto es la ruta del recurso de red no del archivo ni de la carpeta que lo contiene, subí una imagen con un ejemplo de una ejecución exitosa en mi red local, si te das cuenta no tiene más que la dirección IP y el recurso que en tu caso sería:  ´\\180.176.114.15\respaldos´ técnicamente lo único que tienes que hacer es copiar el código que pegue en la respuesta al archivo bat y cambiar el usuario y contraseña.