# ¿Cómo transferir una imagen por SMB y enviarla por PHP al cliente?

Tags: php, html, samba

Buen día,

Cuento con un servidor Linux ejecutando Samba para compartir carpetas en redes Windows, y mi código esta siendo ejecutado en un servidor Windows con Apache y PHP.

Lo que necesito hacer es traer archivos de imágenes que están guardados en el servidor Linux compartidos por Samba y traerlos a mi servidor Windows para después enviárselos a mi usuario en un HTML, ¿Qué necesito ejecutar en línea de comandos para realizar la transferencia? por que mi idea sería ejecutar la transferencia por medio de un exec() de PHP o ¿que otras medidas (PECL, PEAR o librerías) me recomiendan para hacer/simular la transferencia en SMB?.

Después de ejecutar la transferencia necesito enviarle la imagen a mi usuario en el HTML, para que la pueda visualizar.

Cualquier ayuda o idea será agradecida !

Comment: Lee **[cómo crear una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. **Debes [edit] tu pregunta** con el código que hayas intentado, errores, etc. Usa el [code-snippet](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1547/78) [y las demás funciones tiene Stack Overflow en Español para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tus preguntas y/o respuestas](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Saludos.

Comment: Tienes acceso a ese servidor desde el que intentas mostrarla??

Comment: @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas Si tengo acceso al servidor.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave no tengo código alguno, uno de ejemplo sería de mucha utilidad !

Comment: Que tipo de servidor es el que te da acceso a la foto. WEB, FTP??

Comment: Tu servidor local es un windows y tu código esta en un windows verdad?, si sí revisa mi respuesta asumí un poco esa parte

Comment: @Tabitha Mi servidor local es un linux y mi código está en windows. ¿Cambia mucho de windows a linux?

Comment: Entonces tu servidor local que es linux esta corriendo carpetas compartidas con samba?

Comment: @Tabitha Así es !

Comment: Y tu codigo php productivo corre en windows??

Comment: @Tabitha exacto !

Comment: Jaja ok entonces no hay problema debe de funcionar igual

Comment: Si tu codigo productivo corriera en linux no podriamos usar si quiera archivos bat con comandos de windows por eso eran mis preguntas

Comment: si ya tenes un samba share podes montar la carpeta, donde esta la imagen, dentro de la carpeta desde donde el servidor web toma el php mas info https://serverfault.com/a/107301/442275

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SMB es el acrónimo de Server Message Block** y en Linux se emula con Samba, es usado en ambientes Windows para compartir carpetas, archivos e impresoras, la manera en la que funciona a nivel "terminal de comandos" es que al conectarte con el equipo destino se debe de manejar una sesión SMB con el comando **"net use"**, en mi respuesta a esta pregunta puedes ver un ejemplo de como realizar una transferencia de archivo con SMB [Problema con PHP y Btach](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/152414/problema-con-php-y-batch/152445#152445) para encontrar como integrar php con batch y SMB, de mi ejemplo tendrías que reescribir el contenido del archivo bat para cambiar que archivo quieres transferir, te recomiendo con la función **file_put_contents()**.

Después de transferida la imagen sólo hay que escribir el código para enviarla al usuario y para enviar un HTML que la muestre.

Código de PHP para enviar la imagen  (tal vez debas de cambiar algo la parte del content-type) este lo tendrías que pegar en un archivo que se llame p.ej. imagentransferida.php:

```
<?php

    $lstrArchivo = 'nombre y ruta del archivo enviado por smb.gif';

    //código para crear el archivo bat que hace el copiado del servidor local de windows
    $lstrCodigoCMD = '';
    $lstrCodigoCMD .= 'net use "\\64.233.160.1\carpeta" /user:"usuario" "contrasena" /persistent:no' .  "\n";
    $lstrCodigoCMD .= 'copy "\\64.233.160.1\carpeta\archivoimagen.txt" "' . $lstrArchivo . '"' .  "\n";
    $lstrCodigoCMD .= 'net use "\\64.233.160.1\carpeta" /delete /yes' . "\n";
    file_put_contents('C:/xampp/htdocs/rutayarchivo.bat',$lstrCodigoCMD);

    //código para ejecutar el archivo bat
    exec('C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c "C:/xampp/htdocs/rutayarchivo.bat"');

    if (file_exists($lstrArchivo)) {
        header('Content-Disposition: inline');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($lstrArchivo).'"');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($lstrArchivo));
        readfile($lstrArchivo);
        exit;
    }

?>
```

Y para enviar tu html algo como:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Titulo de html</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="imagentransferida.php">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Mil gracias, funciona bien, ahora la pregunta es.. ¿se puede hacer eso que hiciste en el cmd con código php?

Comment: Creo que si, hay varias librerías para abrir sesiones de linea de comando como un terminal o abrir un procedimiento pero sería lo mismo que ejecutar el "net use" a menos que exista una librería pear o pecl que la simule ... tambien algo que te puedo recomendar mucho ver es los comandos de PSTools son excelentes para manejo de sesiones de Windows, o en tu caso podrias instalar herramientas de SSH y con un solo exec de scp hacer la transferencia, hay un mundo de opciones, ... Si te gusto mi respuesta votala positivo plz

Comment: Creo que no había entendido bien tu pregunta de ¿se puede hacer eso que hiciste en el cmd con código php? pues si como escribí primero tienes que escribir el archivo bat y después ejecutarlo, expandí mi respuesta para que también puedas ver como escribir ese código en PHP, también mande a editar tu pregunta para hacerla más precisa.

Comment: Mil gracias, ya aprobé la edición, ahora probaré el código, pero tengo una pregunta, ¿file_put_contents se encarga de crear el .bat ?

Comment: file_put_contents() es lo mismo que hacer un $fp = fopen('C:/xampp/htdocs/rutayarchivo.bat', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $lstrCodigoCMD); fclose($fp); sólo que es más sencillo escribirlo con una sola linea de comando que lo hace ser más fácil de leer y escribir aquí la documentación http://php.net/manual/es/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: Probé el código y me sale el siguiente error: 
Warning: readfile(C:/Users/Dell/Documents/servidor): failed to open stream: Permission denied  ¿Cómo podría mitigar dicho error?

Comment: Ahí lo que dice es que estas tratando de leer un "archivo" al que no tienes "permisos" de acceder, la pregunta necesaria es si esa ruta corresponde a un archivo, y si PHP tiene permisos para leer dicho archivo ¿Existe el archivo o es un directorio o algo más? ¿tienes permisos de lectura? Lo que te recomendaría es que el archivo que obtienes después del copiado remoto lo guardes dentro de tu htdocs y uses un .htaccess para no permitir la lectura no permitida de ese archivo